# How to solve MiKTeX fatal error?

Tags: miktex

I have a problem when compiling my LaTeX code with MiKTeX 2.9 on a Windows 10 PC. The error message is shown below. The problem is not removed by deleting all the auxiliary LaTeX files. The MiKTeX was downloaded as the latest available code last week (January 2018). Any help to solve this problem is appreciated!

[image: 2]

Comment: Run on a command line `updmap`.

Comment: Ulrikke Fisher: how do I run an "updmap", and what will it tell me?

Comment: Simply open a command line (Win-key + R, enter "cmd"), type `updmap` and hit enter. It will update your local map files. In 95% of all cases this solves such problem. If not you will have to make a minimal example.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer: Thanks for your advice. I will test it out.